# Subdivision modifier renders with Viewport Subdivisions in Edit Mode

Tags: rendering

Modelling a mask in Blender. Used subdivision modifier with 1 subdivision on the Viewport and 2 on the render. Like this:

[image]

I made sure the render and realtime buttons were active as can be seen above.

In object mode, behaviour is what I expected, 1 subdivision applied in the Viewport, 2 in the render, like so:

Object mode Viewport

[image]

Object mode Render

[image]

If I enter Edit Mode, the viewport still behaves as expected, but the render always shows the number of subdivisions set for viewport, like so:

Edit Mode Viewport

[image]

Edit Mode Render

[image]

I am new to Blender, do we have to exit Edit Mode and then render?

Comment: To see the modifier settings enable the last button, the one with an inverted triangle. That is the one that enables visibility of the modifier in edit mode.

Answer (score -1):

I am also new to Blender and noticed this recently. I believe it's due to the fact that you cannot apply modifiers (e.g. Subdivision Surface) while in Edit Mode. When you render, it still takes into account whether you're in Object or Edit Mode. So yes I believe you must be in Object mode for the modifier to be applied during the render.